# Transformations of Java Compiler

Tags: java, jls, java-memory-model

According to [section 17.4 of JLS8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) there are two Transformations of the Java Code performed by the Compiler:

1. Statement Reordering
2. Forward Substitution

Is there any other transformations which can be performed by the Java Compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is other transformations, according to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) :

> [The memory model] provides a great deal of freedom for the implementor to perform a **myriad of code transformations**, including the reordering of actions and **removal of unnecessary synchronization**.

As long as the memory model is respected, compiler implementations are allowed to perform any transformations.